# Is there any way to create an instance of a generic using a Class variable?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

For example, is it possible to do something like this:

```
public void doSomething(Class clazz) {
    List<clazz> list = new ArrayList<clazz>();
    list.add(clazz.newInstance));
}
```

I know this doesn't work, but it shows what I'm trying to get at.  Is there any way to parameterize the creation of generic class?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Why? What would you do with the list?

Comment: How will you decide what to do with the stuff inside other than with `instanceof`?

Comment: The list is just an example of the kind of mechanics I am trying to use.  The real application is different.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
public <T> void doSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    list.add(clazz.newInstance());
}
```

Comment: `public <T> void doSomething(Class<? extends T> clazz) {` would probably be more useful. Although reflection is quite evil.

Comment: @Tom, it would be more useful if the method did something with the list (might be a good idea too) ;)